# How to make selenium hub interacts with specific node

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am running selenium hub in one machine, let it be **hub_machine** and I am registering nodes to that hub from machines(**m1, m2, m3**). I am able to do this part without any problem.
Now using the remote web driver I am passing commands from **m1, m2, m3** to the **hub_machine** to invoke the browser on these machines using the below code.

WebDriver selenium = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());

But when I do this, as three nodes are registered to the hub, hub is creating new session on the first node in the list of available nodes.
How do I specify the hub to create a session on particular node?

Answer (score 5):

I have actually understood the concept of hub and node wrongly.
Instead of interacting with hub and we could interact directly with any of the nodes that are registered to the hub that is running on **hub_machine** .

Trick is to pass the node url to the remote web driver instead of hub url.
Ex : WebDriver selenium = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://(IP Of
 **m1** or **m2** or **m3**):(port used by the node)/wd/hub"),

This way we can interact with the node of our choice.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Keeps giving the following error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find handler for (POST) /wd/node/session`

I'm running a selenium hub, and separate selenium node and trying to point remote webdriver to selenium node